# JQuery selector works, but does not through $post

Tags: jquery, post, jquery-selectors

I have a jquery script that takes the value of the selected radio button and post it to another php script to be processed. I suspect there is something wrong with the selector, but I used

```
$("input[name='act']:checked").val()
```

in the firebug console, and it returned the correct value.

Also, I used an alert to show a popup of the selected value and it returned the correct value using:

```
alert($("input[name='act']:checked").val());
```

The code seems solid as well, as I created a "test" field to post, and the correct value showed up.

Thanks for your help!

jquery code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#driver").click(function(event){
        alert($("input[name='act']:checked").val());

                 $('#mainarea').hide('fast');
                 $('#mainarea').empty();

          $.post(
           "facultyoptions.php",
           {
                act: $("input[name='act']:checked").val(),
                test: 'test'
           },
            function(data) {
                $('#mainarea').empty();
                $('#mainarea').append(data);
                $('#mainarea').show('slow');
             }

          );
      });
   });



   </script>
```

HTML

```
<form id="facultyportal" name="facultyportal" method="post" action="facultyoptions.php">

<input type="radio" id="blank" name="act" value="blank"/>
</br>
<input type="radio" id="copy" name="act" value="copy" />
</br>
<input type="radio" id="temp" name="act" value="temp"/>
</br>

<input type="button" id="driver" class="btn btn-danger" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

facultyoptions.php

```
<?php

echo 'HI</br>';

echo $_POST['act'];

echo $_POST['test'];

?>
```

Results:

Hi
Test

Comment: If it helps, in Firebug you can use the Net tab to view the exact HTTP request (to see headers / what was posted)

Comment: Thanks for the Net tab info. I gave it a shot, and it shows that only the test field was posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return false` at the end of the `click` handler, or use `event.preventDefault()` at the start of the handler.

Otherwise you are doing a normal submit which refreshes the pages.

So

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#driver").click(function(event){
            //alert($("input[name='act']:checked").val());

            $('#mainarea').hide('fast');
            $('#mainarea').empty();

            $.post("facultyoptions.php",{
                  act: $("input[name='act']:checked").val(),
                  test: 'test'
                },function(data) {
                   $('#mainarea').empty();
                   $('#mainarea').append(data);
                   $('#mainarea').show('slow');
                });

            return false;
      });
   });
```

oh, and remove the alert as that might interfere with your attempt to stop the normal submit.

---

***Update** for completeness*

After a discussion in the comments, we identified the problem to the `.empty()` call.

The relevant `input` element was inside the `#mainarea` element and so it was getting removed before accessing it..

Comment: I tried your code, still no luck. I was under the impression that if I made it type="button", the form would not submit, so I would not have to return false / preventDefault()

Comment: @rawrzors perhaps you are right about that.. Open up the console and check if your data gets submitted..

Comment: Firebug says that only the test field is being posted to facultyoptions.php. Not sure why though.

Comment: @rawrzors is the `input` element inside `#mainarea` ? because you `empty()` that before accessing the input (*if so the `input` will be removed from the DOM*)..

Comment: That was it! Something so silly and simple. I removed the .empty() and everything is working as it should Thanks.

Comment: :) glad to help.. alternatively you could cache the value to a variable before the `.empty` and use that variable to the `.post()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to not submit the form

So attach to the submit event and use preventDefault - no need to append after empty

```
$(function() {
  $("#facultyportal").on("submit",function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    var act = $("input[name='act']:checked").val();// save before emptying
    $('#mainarea').empty().hide('fast');
    $.post("facultyoptions.php",{act: act,test: 'test'},
      function(data) {
        $('#mainarea').html(data).show('slow');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried your code and replaced my input type="button" with input type="submit" , but it still does not work.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? messages in the console? does the normal form submit return the expected data?

Comment: Same output as in original post.

Comment: so my original thought of not calling empty at all would have shown the issue, although you needed the empty if you wanted to remove previous results... Sheez. Anyway my code now also works